# How to make an AWS S3 bucket accessible over HTTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http

Does `AWS S3` provide a way to make bucket's files available over `HTTP` preferably protected with `BASIC_AUTH`? I mean listing the files (index) and make it possible to download them over `HTTP`.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Download - yes.** Simply set each Object ACL to be publicly readable.
2. **List - sort of.** If you set the Bucket ACL to publicly readable anyone can list the content. However it's a rather human-unfriendly XML listing.

   You can generate your directory listings to some `index.html` files through an external process and configure the bucket to serve those.
3. **Basic auth - nope.** You can look at something like [S3 pre-signed URLs](https://aws.nz/best-practice/s3-presigned-url/) to protect the content.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is mounting the bucket as `s3fs` and serving the root folder as usually done by Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mlu answer, you can put Cloud front in front of the bucket and implement basic auth and probably listing/sorting with a Lambda@edge function.